# Please Help me identify this PT 1K ohm resistor's (Packaging)

Tags: resistors, identification, components

Please refer to the attached Images.

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. [image: pins]

Dimensions:

Hieght and Breadth: 42mm

Thickness: 25mm

I know its PT 1k Ohm resistor(Positive Temperature Coefficient) and its two connecting wires are broken. But i want to know what kind of housing it is.

Comment: Where is the picture with the leads?

Comment: @GustavoLitovsky: Well tats the part i broke! it had two connecting wires, similar to a resistor!

Comment: You didn't mention that. Why don't you go to mouser, digikey or another distributor and just pick up another resistor that'll work?

Comment: wats the point in downvoting the question if the TAGS are available!

Comment: @GustavoLitovsky: because i am looking for the specific dimensions!

Comment: @sheetansh We can not tell you the dimensions, you need calipers or a ruler for that. Downvotes have to do with a measure of your research effort, not if the tags are available.

Comment: @sheetansh measuring the package will help finding out the package type. A picture of the sides where the leads went is also useful. Were the leads short smd style, leadless, or were they long leads like a through hole resistor? Were they both on the same side, or one on each side?

Comment: @sheetansh unfortunately, due to smd miniaturization, trying to find that exact resistor or packaging is next to impossible without knowing the manufacturer. It's not a common chip type resistor, and while there are smd resistors with leads, there is no common packaging like there is with multi-pin sot or soic or tssop or dip.

Comment: @Passerby: thanks for your insight i found the REAL packaging.its PT1000 TO92 Flat.

Comment: @GustavoLitovsky: thanks for your insight i found the REAL packaging.its PT1000 TO92 Flat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, OP found the part number. PT1000 TO92.
(Picture shows 100ohm version of the TO92 variant)

[image]

This does not conform to the TO92 Standard as defined by [JEDEC Transistor Outline Package, Case Style 92 (PDF)](http://www.jedec.org/sites/default/files/docs/archive/to/to-092.pdf), which is a three pin package, and nearly always has a fully curved face opposite the flat face. Understandably, this makes it harder to identify, as most would not consider it a TO92 package.

Comment: http://www.voelkner.de/products/28482/Platin-Temperatur-Sensor-Pt-1000-to-92.html
the reason why i wrote TO92, none the less thanks for correcting me.

Comment: @sheetansh not correcting you, you are correct. It's the manufacturer that is using a non-standard case. It's like asking someone to pass the salt, when they mean pepper. Just pointing out why noone was able to identify it at first glance.